# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\sin kx}{k}$ converges absolutely/conditionally/uniformly?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\sin kx}{k}$ converges absolutely/conditionally/uniformly?$

If we just consider $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin kx}{k}$, then Dirichlet test gives us the answer. What about adding $(-1)^k$?

Comment: The terms have the same absolute value. So the series either both converge absolutely or both do not.

Comment: Start by summing from $k=1$ to $k=n$,Write $$(-1)^k\sin(kx)=\Delta (-1)^{k+1}\sin((k-1/2)x)\sec(x/2)$$where $\Delta$ is the forward difference operator $$\Delta f(k)=f(k+1)-f(k)$$ and do summation by parts.

Comment: Sorry-I forgot a factor of 1/2 just before $\sec(x/2).$

Comment: Think of it this way: $(-1)^k\sin kx$ is just $\sin k(x+\pi)$.

Comment: We have $$2|\sin (kx)|\ge 2\sin^2 (kx)=1-\cos(2kx)$$ The series $\sum {\cos(2kx)\over k} $ is convergent for $0<x<\pi $ but the series $\sum {1\over k}$ is divergent hence the series $ \sum {|\sin (kx)|\over k}$ is divergent for $0<x<\pi.$